# C Struct Unioned with a Char Array

Tags: c, serial-port, pic

I'm trying to receive a record in binary from a PIC programmed in C.

The data sent is structured so:

```
typedef struct{int32 num1;
              float num2,num3,num4,num5;
              ...
              }RecordStructure;

typedef union{RecordStructure Record; char Array[48];} My_Rec_Structure;
```

My question is this:

Do the first 4 bytes/chars belong to the `int32 num1`, the next 4 to `float num2` and so on?

If so I'm having major issues with transmission;  if not, how do I discern where the data ended up?

Comment: Any struct padding #pragmas in your compiler? If so, you should use them to be sure of your struct layout. The items should be in the same order but there may be padding between them. Especially relevant as you're dealing with an 'interesting' architecture.

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure.  This is a product made by someone else;  I cab talk to him and figure it out, but I doubt he even knows.  He's an Electrical Engineer dabbling in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How data is aligned within a struct can vary between compilers as well as the pragmas used to force a particular alignment.

If this compiler aligns items on a double word boundary then the first 4 bytes, num1, should line up with the first 4 bytes of the char Array, the second four bytes, num2, with the second four bytes of the char Array, etc.

If possible what you can do is to use a debugger to examine the data when it is received.  And in the data that is sent you put a specific hex digit sequence so that you can know whether things are lining up as you think or not.

So on the PIC the data sent in the struct might be:

```
RecordStructure myRecord;
myRecord.num1 = 01F2E3D4C;
myRecord.num5 = myRecord.num4 = myRecord.num3 = myRecord.num2 = 0;
```

Then send that across to see what it looks like. and whether the num1 value is the same.

If you then modify the data for instance if myRecord.num3 = 1.0 you will be able to see if things line up or not.

Comment: In the case of num1, num2, etc....  I can get num1 to decode.  It should follow a pattern of 0, 40, 80, 120, etc.  I can decode that, but for some reason at the start of the 120 record an extra byte has been inserted, and then instead of getting 160 for the next I get a byte with value 253.  I HAVE tried both little Endian and Big Endian;  little Endian is the only way I can decode num1 for the first 3 records.

Comment: 253 is 0xFD.  0xFD is used (by MS and possibly others) as NoMansLand, which is a memory barrier set on each side of the memory used by an application in debug mode to indicate you have gone outside of the allocated memory.  I don't know if the PIC compiler does this as well, but it could help indicate your problem.

Comment: @Sheriff What is the entire RecordStructure struct look like?  What are the other elements?  What I am wondering is if the struct RecordStructure is not 48 bytes in length then the union is going to make the size to be 48 bytes since the char array is 48 elements.  How are you doing the transfer and how do you specify the number of bytes to transfer?

Comment: @RichardChambers I figured it out.  It does indeed have 48 bytes,  but he was adding an additional 10 mS delay between bytes;  this threw the whole thing off sometimes.  It is all via RS-232, at 115kbaud.

Answer (score 3):

Yes on the first part, but with a caveat.

The C standard requries that the first struct member is placed at the beginning of the structure. So the int32 will be the first four bytes transferred. However, the PIC might have a different byte ordering, so you might end up sending 0x12345678 from the PIC, and reading the value 0x78563412 at the receiving end.

As for the adressing of the remaining struct members, your compiler are free to add padding between each member. Typically this is something that's done in order to optimize memory access.

If you have the posibility to get some text output from your PIC, you can get the offsets for the structure members by using the offsetof() macro from stddef.h:

```
fprintf(stderr, "num2 offset=%d\n", offsetof(RecordStructure, num2));
fprintf(stderr, "num3 offset=%d\n", offsetof(RecordStructure, num3));
```

Comment: Jesus.  This will not be fun then.  It really does look like there may be padding.  I can get something very similar to what I expect if I occasionally eat an extra byte.

Comment: If you have the bandwidth between PIC and host, you could write out the valuses with sprintf() at the PIC, and then reading them with sscanf() at the receiving end. As long as you have a limited number of structures to pass, and your PIC environment can handle stdio, this will be the fastest af safest way to transfer the data.

Comment: @Sheriff **Usually**, there is no padding between members of the same size, padding is only added where it's needed for alignment. So _probably_ the `int32` and the four `float`s take up the first twenty bytes of the struct (and the union). It's not guaranteed to be so by the standard, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer   turns out it was a timing issue.  he was adding a 10mS delay sometimes, AND apparently his compiler was using little-endian versus my big-endian.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The first four bytes will belong to num1, then the next four bytes will belong to num2, etc.  The byte ordering within the ints and floats, however, are platform and implementation-specific.

There are two major things that will affect this, however.  One is alignment and the other is padding.  Make sure to set padding to 1 byte to ensure that you get no memory gaps between the variables and set alignment to 1 if possible as well.  But depending on your compiler and hardware, alignment may have to be a multiple of 4 or 8 bytes for example.  In this case you may need to add some padding variables.  You can use the align keyword in MSVC and the alignment attribute in GCC to change the default alignment per-structure/variable:

```
__declspec(align(1)) //MSVC
__attribute__((aligned(1))) //GCC
```

Example:

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct{int32 num1;
              float num2,num3,num4,num5;
              ...
              }RecordStructure;

typedef union{RecordStructure Record; char Array[48];} My_Rec_Structure;
```

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://github.com/mru00/SampleScope/blob/06e12c9c1c836ed2f4e12b0869acd6b6d283a3e0/shared/common.h) shows how the same definition of ~RecordStructure~ can be used on both sides, PC (Linux/x86/gcc) and PIC(18F).  The trick is to use `#ifdef / #define` to support both compilers.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
# define __PACKED
# define __PACKED2 __attribute__((packed))
#else
# define __PACKED2
#endif


typedef struct __PACKED {
    opcodes_t opcode : 8;
    union {
        osci_config_t set_config_args;
        READ_SINGLE_ARGS read_single_args;
        SAMPLE_SINGLE_ARGS sample_single_args;
        SAMPLE_INTERLEAVED_ARGS sample_interleaved_args;
    } args;
} __PACKED2 opcode_decoder_t;
```